# Can't definine classes and properties in Stardog

Tags: rdf, stardog

I am starting using `Stardog` Database and at the very beginning I came across problem I an unable to solve.

I Have created `database` and then by typing :
[image]

I imported existing ontology into this `database`. I am able to see those `triples` in `Stardog` 
[image]

However when I want to browse this database to see `properties` and `classes` I see only `Thing` and when I try to use either `class` or `property` I see "`No matches fount`" info:
[image]

Could anyone give me a hint How can I add some classes to my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stardog (and thus the web console) limits which parts of the database it obtains the schema information from by default.

From the [Stardog documentation](http://docs.stardog.com/#_configuration_options) a database has a `reasoning.schema.graphs` option which is described as follows:

> Determines which, if any, named graph or graphs contains the "tbox",
>   i.e., the schema part of the data.

And if we look at the associated [Javadoc](http://docs.stardog.com/java/snarl/com/complexible/stardog/db/DatabaseOptions.html#SCHEMA_GRAPHS) for that property we can see the default for it:

> Option to specify the location where the schema should be extracted
>   from. Expected to be a list of the graph URIs which are the context
>   names schema axioms should be extracted from. The default value is the
>   default (no context) graph

So Stardog is by default only considering the default unnamed graph when extracting the schema for the database.

However in your example you explicitly load your ontology into a named graph so Stardog will not automatically extract the schema from it.  To fix this you can do one of two things:

1. Load your ontology into the default graph
2. Edit the `reasoning.schema.graphs` option for your database to point to include the named graph with your ontology

Please refer to the aforementioned Stardog documentation for how to change the configuration options for a database.

Answer (score 0):

Stardog currently only extracts the schema in the webconsole from the default graph, so you'll have to move it there if you want to use the web console, or stick with the CLI or programmatic access.  Also, as @RobV points out, you'll have to tell it where you've put the schema if you've loaded it somewhere other than the default graph.